# How to testfor blocks not people

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

how do I testfor blocks?  like if I put down stone near a command block with a comparator attached to it and it will activate a piston connected by the comparator on the command block? please answer.

Answer (score 5):

The command you want is /testforblock. The syntax of it is:

```
testforblock <x> <y> <z> <TileName> [dataValue] [dataTag]
```

So to test for a stone block at X=10, Y=64, Z=10, the command would be:

```
testforblock 10 64 10 stone
```

Comment: Could you also test for a block relative for the command block, say, like this: /testforblock ~ ~-1 ~ stone

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms Yep.

Comment: Note that `/testforblock` is an upcoming feature and not yet in the latest stable version (1.7.9).

Answer (score 0):

## 1.13+ Update

`/testforblock` has been deprecated. New command is `/execute if block`.

```
/execute if block 10 64 10 stone
```

You can now run a success command directly in the same command:

```
/execute if block 10 64 10 stone run give @p diamond_shovel
```

You can also use `unless` to negate the check:

```
/execute unless block 10 64 10 stone run give @p diamond_shovel
```