# Testfor command for a block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying the `testfor` command on a block, is that possible? When it is mined , I want the testfor to turn off.

[image]

For example, when this green wool block is mined up, the command block that has the `testfor` command will turn off, for it can't find the block there. Can this work somehow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to testfor blocks not people](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/169972/how-to-testfor-blocks-not-people)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have the following command in a command block on clock of some sort or a repeating command block if you are in 1.9:

```
Testforblock x y z wool 5
```

Replace the X,Y, and Z with the coordinates of the block. Because colored wool doesn't have different names for each color, you must use the damage value to testfor the color. The [minecraft wiki page on damage values](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_values#Wool.2C_Stained_Clay.2C_Stained_Glass_and_Carpet) shows that green is value 5 for wool. When it doesn't detect it, the comparator will turn off.

Note: if you put -1 as the damage value it will do it no matter what damage value the block is

Alternatively, this command can be used but the comparator will turn on when it breaks:

```
Testforblock x y z air 0
```

Air doesn't have data values so 0 or -1 is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
testforblock <x> <y> <z> <TileName> [dataValue] [dataTag]
```

Here: [How to testfor blocks not people](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/169972/how-to-testfor-blocks-not-people)

Comment: Don't copy answers from one question to another -- flag the question as duplicate instea.